# Latex (String formula to Image) for IOS

Tags: ios, latex

I've done my [math application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathlogic.schoolmath2) for Android.
I use [JLatex](https://github.com/mksmbrtsh/jlatexmath-android) Library to convert math expressions to Bitmap.
I have a lot of predefined strings with math expressions (in my crossplatform C++ core).
Now I'm working on IOS version. I want to use that core here.
But I face with Latex problem.

---

Are there JLatex alternatives for IOS?

---

I've found some Libraries, but syntax isn't the same...
Syntax of JLatex is the same as [here](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Comment: how did you manage to solve this ?? any option other than iosMath

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta, I stopped on `iosMath`, didn't search for alternative for a long time.

Comment: Okk thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found great Latex Library for IOS.
It's [iosMath](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath).

---

Currently it has only one defect: doesn't support line break.
But I believe it'll be done soon.